# drupal rebuild content access HTTP error 503 occurred

Tags: drupal, http-status-code-503

I have a multisite drupal  installation with domain access module. Off late, I have started getting this warning 'need to build access permission'. Also, I went tried rebuild the access permission, I get 'An HTTP error 503 occurred. /batch?id=24&op=do'

The solutions suggest that I disable the modules and rebuild the content access permissions.

the sites seem to have suddenly gone beserk. I get access denied for for unauthenticated users.

I have live sites. Is there an alternative solution to it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are using malconfigured content access modules, probably the domain access module you mention, and possibly others: Taxonomy Access Control (or TAC Lite), Access Control, Nodeaccess - stuff like that. Their permissions might be clashing with each other and with Drupal's core Permissions module. Revise them and, if necessary, uninstall the modules and try reinstalling+reconfiguring them. And yes, definitely rebuild access permissions afterwards.

Also, make sure your server isn't overloaded or something. The 503 errors, plus the previous issue you posted, possibly involving script execution timeouts, might indicate your server can't handle your Drupal install. Remember that Drupal is highly db-intensive and it's generally not the best idea to use a multisite Drupal install for high traffic sites.

Can't think of anything else, sorry...

Comment: Thanks @mingos..I guess thats the only alternative but what I fail to understand is that why suddenly the site has begun acting funny.. Uptill now, it was working smooth. ALl of a sudden, pages load slow, warnings appear, modules have begun throwing errors. Could increasing load on the MYSQL server be a possible problem to all issues? Is is advisable to scale the db and use a cluster with load balanacing. Would it be a feasible long term solution?

Comment: I am currently using 2 servers for data and webserver and I have tried all basic optimizing techniques for mysql optimization and webserver.

Comment: @Loveleen, I do not know the specifics of your site, so I can't really answer your question thoroughly. But yes, increased load on the MySQL server can be problematic. I myself get timeout errors sometimes when working with one client's site - and the only workaround is reducing MySQL load to a minimum, but finally we decided to change the host and the problems automagically disappeared together with a better hosting account. I wish I could be of more help, but alas, my knowledge of the server technicalities is somewhat limited.

Comment: Thanks @mingos. Perhaps changing the host would be the best thing to start of with and then we can make incremental changes in case if it doesnt work.

Comment: Yes. Many hosts offer a 7 day trial, so it's a great way to test the host before actually making a purchase. Best of luck to you!